# Python - Printing 2 array elements for each line

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I would like to create a (for) loop that print 2 Array elements for each line. You'll understand better with an example:

```
array = ["A","B","C","D"]
```

The output I want is:

```
A B
C D
```

How I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: What if your list has an odd number of elements, like so ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']?

Comment: yep. doesn't work

Comment: @ŽeljkoJelić could be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good posts earlier to learn more about Python looping of `list`. Here is a simple way to get what you expected output - regardless of this list has even or odd items.

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']   # can add 'E' to try odd number items.
for i, ch in enumerate(lst, 1):
    print(ch, end='\t')
    if i % 2 == 0:    # check to see if it hit the interval threshold?
        print()       # if you want 3 items in a row, you can change 2 to 3
```

```
Output
A   B
C   D
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the list and print 2 items with the print command.  You can specify 2 as the increment for iterating, and join part of the list, and can handle odd numbers too.  The slice of a list goes up to but not including the 2nd number, so slice with i:i+2.  At the end of an odd-length list, there will be no 2nd item but the slice won't give an index-out-of-range error:

```
list1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    print(' '.join(list1[i:i+2]))
```

to get

```
A B
C D
E
```